# Initialization object type based on derived class where initialization is performed in base class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Having the following `BaseField` class:

```
export abstract class BaseField<T>  {
  public abstract readonly controlType: ControlType;
  public key: string;
  public label: string;
  public order?: number;
  public value?: T;

  constructor(init?: Partial<Field<T>>) {
    return Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

Derived fields classes:

```
export class TextBoxField<T> extends BaseField<T> {
  public readonly controlType = ControlType.TextBox;
  public minLength: number;
  public maxLength: number
}

export class DropdownField<T> extends BaseField<T>{
  public readonly controlType = ControlType.Dropdown;
  public options?: Option<Date | string | number>;
}

export class NumberField<T> extends BaseField<T> {
  public readonly controlType = ControlType.Number;
  public min: number;
  public max: number;
}

export type Field<T> =
  | DropdownField<T>
  | TextBoxField<T>
  | NumberField<T>

export enum ControlType {
  Dropdown,
  TextBox,
  Number,
}
```

When instantiating a derived field, unlike the current behavior where its constructor accepts an initialization object of a union type (due to `BaseFeild` accepting `Field` which is a union type of the derived classes), I would like it to accept the corresponding initialization object based on the derived class specific type. (as an example `TextBoxField` shouldn't accepts `min` property which belongs to `NumberField`).

Is there any way of achieving this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Could you make this code a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  As it stands there are undeclared types and values and some `--strict` mode errors that are obstacles to overcome before I can even try to come up with a solution.

Comment: I've added the undeclared types

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is one of the most annoying places to try to enforce the constraint you're mentioning.  In other cases I'd suggest using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), a type that automatically refers to the type of the "current" class or interface.  But the constructor is a static member and therefore cannot use polymorphic `this`; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for a feature request to support it.

There's a workaround for static methods that allows you to use a generic [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) to get similar behavior, but again, you can't do that here because constructors are not allowed to have `this` parameters:

```
class Sad {
  // constructor(this: any) { }; // error!
  // --------->  ~~~~~~~~~
  // A constructor cannot have a 'this' parameter
}
```

nor are they allowed to have generic type parameters:

```
class Mad {
  constructor<T>() { }; // error!
  // -------> ~
  // Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration
}
```

So you can't do that.

---

Instead, the closest I can get is to give up on the built-in polymorphic `this` and instead reimplement it manually with [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

```
abstract class BaseField<T, This extends BaseField<T, This>>  {
  public abstract readonly controlType: ControlType;
  public value?: T;
  constructor(init?: Partial<This>) {
    return Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}
```

The added type parameter named `This` is intended to be filled in by subclasses, like so:

```
class TextBoxField<T> extends BaseField<T, TextBoxField<T>> {
  public readonly controlType = ControlType.TextBox;
  public minLength: number = 0;
  public maxLength: number = 1
}

class NumberField<T> extends BaseField<T, NumberField<T>> {
  public readonly controlType = ControlType.Number;
  public min: number = 0;
  public max: number = 1;
}
```

That's how you'd do this sort of thing in Java ([for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#Example) `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {...}`.  Yes, it's redundant and leaves open the possibility of being done incorrectly by a subclass: (think `class OopsField extends BaseFileld<T, SomeOtherField> {}`), but if used properly it behaves the way you want:

```
const bad = new TextBoxField({ min: 1 }); // error!
const good = new TextBoxField({ minLength: 2 }); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9iALgJzgGwCoE8AOwoDeAsAFBRQbAAeiAQnFQDRQBykARsMqQL6mK58ANQCGaAJYATEYjjIoAXigAxMCADGicQgDcpUurQiAzsagBlEZMKlyAejtR1CYyjCa5ACkQALccYAuKBEQLABKQigeHSgHKC5UZABCW1jHAFpMrKyAPnIAP0KiotS4gEEnFzcPeXUQkDhEKB8RADd8ESgAcl9-LqgcEWQRCGBELl59EkMTMwBZKxsySpBXZHdZZAAeDBzPCIIomLiEuRTluOzcqHzSx2w8AaGRsa4zOpAGppEcPCGoBDBFZrDZyKCSYAzYZaBCTEhTETsNYiTROIymKC0EzAZTiYBoSQ7ZgYPxmajjECSMxY4w4vEEokUUk5PJLcg4MDsCTqYJIlAoprIYBWBBoLArFDoB7AILwJCoTCCPTLDlc8Q8gDWwCwQTW4hAAHNFFAAEQak3K9mc7lQIycNC6lD6o1KE1oC2pVU2uQQ5AAfiC4AgnGQloG1vVUFaYjAwADFDDXsj0Yk0hhq3jolTMjkAG0ALrGgvK1LOVbVTaefXiRDxgAKQy0Yh2zIOqXIQsQYGQICgAHl2AArSGIAB0s3EBpA3lJzGriDCYb4JGXBnRZkoNHoVFx+MJu3iNFAVMx2N3DIwxPJ2-P+5ZbPDap5QpFIDFEoV0uNcslirwo83OgGETCMeQgfUABlQANXxAw4LhjQABhAp8oAgEQqCgw1YKgIMQ2NABGOE11mVh4OQW8djyclj2pM96X3Zg2GDLhKN2PJiBVUCoBfSRRXFMtfy-JQf0-QRR2YkMUJtcCQDglj5CUZDPW49CqHk-ClAI5VVxIagcDkJoBEeNi8gUVIAB8KGvBhTMssiFLs+FpiqKB2EWJQQGAAB3ayt1shjPEOWSggIqJFzSeJkESc4y1cKADTgOBrE8ny-KAndAuCyDoJwgAmcLjkcOANRELAgA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!